# Confused regarding this statement about "function call by reference."

Tags: c++, pointers, terminology

What I'm confused about is whether the question is asking about passing arguments to functions as references (as opposed to "Call by Value") or about how we can set a pointer to point to a function.

The exact question is:

***"Explain the function call by reference giving a suitable example in support of your answer."***

The way it's termed makes it feel like it's asking about the latter. In my head, it seems as if it's asking how a function is called by reference, i.e, using a pointer.

C++ for what I'm talking about: int (*ptr)(int, int);
Which can later be assigned to a function like int max(int a, int b);

I know this is a bit of an odd post for Stack since it's more of an English question, but it's the only place I could think to ask.

EDIT: A lot of people are asking what I mean by the second thing. Since I'm new to the concept, I'll just copy - paste what my textbook gives as an example: (Sorry for the terrible formatting, sorry!)

```
main() {

int max(int a, int b){...}; //Your typical maximum function
int (*ptr)(int, int);
ptr = max;

//Then if you want to run the program

m = (*ptr)(2, 5);
cout << m; //Outputs 5
}
```

Comment: I never heard of that concept, where did you find it?

Comment: "Explain the function call by reference giving a suitable example in support of your answer." - Ambiguous/unclear. Go ask the person who posed that question/task what they really mean.

Comment: @JVApen in my textbook :P We were never taught it in class and it seems like an oddball concept that nobody actually uses. The only use our textbook gives us is to display the "address" of where a function is (which nobody really needs to do) by making a pointer point to the function and then do cout << ptr.

Comment: Is this what you mean if so please edit your question - live link: https://godbolt.org/g/6eoQXc

Comment: @JesperJuhl I guess I'll do that, but this question is given to us under the chapter "Pointers" which is why a lot of questions are like that.

Comment: I would not call that example "function call by reference".  I'd call it a "function call by function pointer".

Comment: I've got a feeling OP means this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm

Comment: @KillzoneKid if I'm not wrong, that's what I meant to say when I was talking about the first option. "Call by Reference" as opposed to "Call by Value" (except it's a bit different in C++, compared to the C example you gave)

Comment: @RichardCritten hadn't seen that before! That seems the answer they were going for, but you never know with these teachers :/

Comment: That's why we are confused - call by pointer is __probably__ what you are being asked about but the use of _reference_ in the question has us confused.

Comment: You are asking about calling a function using function pointer. Your example correctly represents the concept.